# Hiding a zsh completion

Tags: autocomplete, zsh

I just switched to `zsh` (from `tcsh`) and have only run into one serious frustration:  There are multiple completions for `push` — `pushd` and `pushln`.  I’d really like to only have `pushd` available, since this is really tripping up my muscle memory.

How can I set this up using `zsh` completion (specifically `compsys`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to control the completion so precisely, but there is a builtin function called `disable`, which disables a command itself.

If you add `disable pushln` to your `.zshrc`, the `pushln` builtin will be disabled and no longer be displayed as a candidate.

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your issue?

```
alias push='pushd'
```

Comment: No, because that just means there'll be three completions for `push` rather than two.  I want to start typing `push` (e.g. type either `pus` or `push`) and have the only completion be `pushd`.